# Compress m4a file created on the iphone before uploading them to the server

Tags: ios7, compression, core-audio

I have merged two streams of caff files into one streo file with the format of m4a/caff

the properties of the files are the following:

> 44100 Hz, 16bit stereo,  256kb/sec

for a 31 seconds file i get a 667 KB
what can i do to reduce the size of this file after the fact..?
can i convert it to a single channel (mono)? can i reduce the sample size or something like that?
I tried several sample application out their - but none of them gave me a good solution.

Do you have any idea? 
Using this command line on the mac worked - but i don't know how to do it on iphone

```
sudo afconvert -d aac -f 'caff' -b 32768 call_record.m4a test_32.caf
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd use the ExtAudioFile API to do the conversion. To reduce the size you could convert to a compressed format like AAC. See some sample code here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I already have a compressed file format (m4a is aac) . the problem is that it is streo with CD sample rate and high bitrate - i want to know how to reduce this parameters in order to result in a smaller file size.

Comment: i ended up compiling ffmpeg for iphone and using it to convert m4a to g726 format with 8000Hz and mono instead of stereo.